# Is the conditional expectation a contraction in weak $\mathbb L^p$ spaces?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a probability space. It is well-known that if $\mathcal A$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F$, $p\geqslant 1$ and $X$ is an element of $\mathbb L^p$ which takes real values, then 
$$\tag{1}  \lVert\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\rVert_p\leqslant \lVert X\rVert_p.$$

We now consider for $p\gt1$ the weak $\mathbb L^p$-space, denoted by $\mathbb L^{p,\infty}$, which consists of all the real valued random variables such that 
$\lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}^*:= \left(\sup_{t\gt 0 }t^p\mu\{|X|\gt t\}\right)^{1/p} $ is finite. It is known that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{p,\infty}^*$ is not a norm because the triangle inequality fails. However, defining $$\lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}:=\sup\left\{\mu(A)^{1/p-1}\mathbb E[| X|\cdot\mathbb 1_{A} ], A\in\mathcal F,\mu(A)\gt 0 \right\},$$
then $\lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}$ is a norm and 
$$\tag{2} \lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}^*\leqslant \lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}\leqslant \frac p{p-1}\lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}^*.$$

---

**Questions:**

1. Does the inequality 
   $$\lVert\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\rVert_{p,\infty} \leqslant \lVert X\rVert_{p,\infty}$$
   hold in general?
2. If not, is there a norm $N_p$ on $\mathbb L^{p,\infty}$ which is equivalent to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{p,\infty} $ and for which the inequality 
   $$N_p\left(\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\right)\leqslant N_p(X) $$
   takes place?

---

**Motivations.** In general, subadditive sequences have good properties. If $T\colon\Omega\to\Omega$ is a measure preserving map and $\mathcal M$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal F$ such that $T \mathcal M\subset \mathcal M$, then defining $S_n(f):=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f\circ T^i$ ($f$ is $\mathcal M$-measurable), the sequence $\left(\lVert\mathbb E\left[S_n(f)\mid \mathcal M\right]\rVert_p\right)_{n\geqslant 1} $ is subadditive for any $p\geqslant 1$. A similar result for weak $\mathbb L^p$ norms would be nice.

---

For the first question, we can show that 
$$t\mu\{\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]>t\}^{1/p} \leqslant 
\frac 1{\mu\{\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]>t\}^{1-1/p}}\mathbb E[f\mathbb{1}\{\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]>t\}  ],$$
hence 
$$\lVert \mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\rVert_{p ,\infty}^*\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{p,\infty},$$
and it follows from (2) that 
$$\lVert \mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal A]\rVert_{p ,\infty}\leqslant \frac p{p-1} \lVert f\rVert_{p,\infty},$$
so the question is actually whether we can get rid of the factor $\frac p{p-1}$.

We can try to show this when $f$ is a simple function, but I fail to see how to apply efficiently convexity inequalities.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Real_interpolation

Comment: @AlexanderShamov Indeed, it seems that my question is related to interpolation of Banach spaces. However, I fail to see how to apply one of the methods of interpolation in the link. For example, the connexion of the $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{p ,\infty}$ with the obtained norm in the interpolated space is not clear (to me).  Do you have a precise idea in how to apply the theorem? Anyway  I will study the book by Bennett and Sharpley.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the case $X_0 = L^1$, $X_1 = L^\infty$, $\theta = 1 - \frac{1}{p}$, the functional $K(x, t, X_0, X_1)$ defined in that Wikipedia article coincides with $\sup_{\mu[A] = t} \mathsf{E} |x| \mathsf{1}[A]$. Which makes the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{p,\infty}$ norm exactly equal to the $K(\theta,\infty)$ interpolation norm.

Comment: You are right and i can conclude from Theorem 1.11 301 of Bennett and Shapley. Maybe you could post this as an answer.

Comment: The Calderon-Mitiagin interpolation theorem says that all rearrangement invariant function spaces are exact interpolation spaces between $L_1$ and $L_\infty$.  This is Theorem 2.2 in Bennett-Sharpley and can be found in many other books as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
You can modify your definition of the norm as: $$\|X \|_{p,\infty}=\sup [(\int_\Omega \phi )^{1/p-1}\mathbb{E}(|X|\phi), \text{ } 0\leq \phi \leq 1] $$
Then 
$$\|\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{A}) \|_{p,\infty}=\sup [(\int_\Omega \mathbb{E}(\phi|\mathcal{A}))^{1/p-1}\mathbb{E}(|X|\mathbb{E}(\phi|\mathcal{A})), 0\leq \phi \leq 1] $$

And we can conclude because $0\leq \phi \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0\leq \mathbb{E}(\phi|\mathcal{A})\leq 1$

Answer (score -1):

my typesetting was so bad it wasn't worth posting my answer but the suggestion was to apply neyman pearson lemma to show that you can replace sup over sets A with only sets of form A=(X>C), then compute norm of E(X|A).  I did assume a r.v.s had continuous distributions if convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you include the statement of  Neyman Pearson's lemma?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma in this case take likelihood ratio proportional to X, then it says maximize E(X; A) over P(A) = c by choosing A = (X > A), which is the set where the likelihood ratio, X,  is large.

Comment: Could you please give more details? For the moment I fail to see the connection between likelihood ratios and the context of my question.